# Выполнение скрипта php от www-data

Tags: php, apache, debian

Требуется выполнить на сайте

```
exec ("usr/bin/fswebcam /var/www/cam1/cam1.jpg");
echo "< img src=cam1.jpg > ";
```

выполнение в консоли от рута успешно.
выполнение в консоли `su www-data` выдает:

> This account is currently not available.

`www-data` в группе `data`, 
`/var/www/cam1/` хозяин `www-data`

Использую Debian 8. `sudo` не стоит, поэтому `/etc/sudoers` не предлагать.

Странно, но тот же `exec ("lsusb | grep 04b8:0007")` в браузере исполняется.
Страница на домашнем сервере, так что решение «костылем» приемлемо.

Answer (score 2):

> usr/bin/fswebcam

это относительный путь. относительно текущего каталога. вероятно, подразумевалось `/usr/bin/fswebcam`.

> на сайте

значит, *http*-сервер у вас есть. и, вероятно, рабочие процессы выполняет он от имени пользователя *www-data*. если ещё и поддержка исполнения *php*-скриптов в нём включена, то почему бы этим не воспользоваться?

создайте файл (с произвольным именем и суффиксом `.php`) в *docroot*-е вашего *http*-сервера с нужными вам командами на языке *php*, и вызывайте извне или непосредственно на сервере:

```
$ wget http://ваш.сервер/скрипт.php
```

если вас не интересует результат выполнения, то добавьте соответствующие опции:

```
$ wget -qO /dev/null http://ваш.сервер/скрипт.php
```

---

но если такое решение не подходит, то можно выполнять команды и от имени пользователя, у которого в качестве оболочки прописано что-нибудь вроде `/usr/sbin/nologin`, как у того же пользователя *www-data*.

понятно, что делать это можно лишь от имени пользователя *root*, т.к. программа *su*, выполняемая не от имени *root*-а, запросит пароль целевого пользователя, а у пользователя *www-data* пароль (по умолчанию) отсутствует:

```
# su -s /bin/bash -c "php /путь/к/вашему/скрипту.php" www-data
```

Comment: с первой частью и так все ясно. проблема именно в исполнении exec от www-data. чьих прав как раз мало для бинарника fswebcam.

Comment: думаете дело в одном слеше? кто знает... в консоли root и по fswebcam /var/www/cam1/cam1.jpg выполняет. тут я решил дополнить путь до абсолютного.

Comment: su -s /bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/fswebcam /var/www/cam1/cam1.jpg" www-data
отрабатывает как надо.

Comment: Спасибо. теперь не в чем. Заменил exec на su -s /bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/fswebcam /var/www/cam1/cam1.jpg" www-data
И с веб-страницы идет выполнение.  Так в чем соль была я правда все равно не уловил. Если посоветуете в каком мануале об этом для себя подчеркнуть, буду признателен.

Comment: *Заменил exec на su* — а разве в php есть функция (команда) su?

Comment: *Так в чем соль была я правда все равно не уловил* — а я так и не уловил, что, где и от чьего имени вы выполняете.